# Different pivot tables to different emails vba

Tags: vba, outlook, pivot-table

I have multiple pivot tables that I want to send out individually to different emails.  The problem is, the email keeps getting written over by the second email.  Each pivot table is named different and the code works fine with only one reference.  I have tried multiple ways to get it but cant. Can someone help?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wk As Worksheet
Dim wk1 As Worksheet
wk = Worksheets("EPSICAR")
wk.Connections("owssvr").Refresh
wk1 = Worksheets("PastDue")
wk1.RefreshAll

End Sub

Sub pastdue()

Dim myApp As Outlook.Application, mymail As Outlook.Mailitem
Dim Lap As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngmtl As Range
Dim Mailitem As Object

Set myApp = New Outlook.Application
Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set rng = Sheets("PastDue").PivotTables("Q Group Past 
Due").TableRange1
Set rngmtl = Sheets("PastDue").PivotTables("Mtl Group Past 
Due").TableRange2

With mymail
.To = "sponge.bobh@12345.com"
.CC = "pat.star@12345.com"
.Subject = "ICAR/EPS past due"
.HTMLBody = "The following are a list of ICARs/EPS that are past due" & 
 RangetoHTML(rng)
.Display
'.send


With mymail
.To = "blue.berry@12345.com"
.CC = "black.berry@12345.com"
.Subject = "ICAR/EPS past due"
.HTMLBody = "The following are a list of ICARs/EPS that are past due" & 
RangetoHTML(rngmtl)
.Display
'.send



Set myApp = Nothing
Set mymail = Nothing
End With
End With


End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Send the email before drafting another

Comment: Send email 1, send email 2. Not draft email 1, draft email 2, then send both. Your email is getting overwritten by design

Comment: @urdearboy hello that worked but now im having trouble with the HTML code for the second pivot table.  I change the range and that didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is off a bit.  I suppose there are a few ways to do this kind of thing.  You can refresh the pivot multiple ways, and email a snapshot of each to different recipients.  You could refresh the pivot multiple ways, save each, and email the saved version of each to separate people.  If you want to go down this path, try to code sample below.

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

```
In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)
```

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

There are probably a couple other approaches you could consider.  Just get one thing to work, before trying a different means to the same end.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately that doesn't work for the application I want to do.